# Get CLI results in Django or Flask?

Tags: google-bigquery, command-line-interface

I'm setting up a simple webserver that only needs to query my dataset at Google's BigQuery.  Currently, I'm trying this with Python 2.7 and Django.

I've installed Google's Python API Client, OAuth2, and other libraries.  But I can't get past an ImportError.

So I installed the bigquery module, which lets me successfully query my data on the command line.

Is it possible to have Django (or Flask, or some other lightweight Python web framework) call the command line script, and return its results?